# Help me set up my routers

Tags: windows, networking, home-networking

I have two routers:

1. SpeedTouch 585 DSL + 4-LAN
2. DLink DI-604 WAN + 4-LAN

One LAN port of the SpeedTouch goes to the DLink WAN. 
Two LAN ports on the DLink connects two computers.

This works, but I'm not sure if it's correctly set up. As it seems to be advised to use LAN-to-LAN between the routers. Should I change this? Or doesn't it matter? I will only connect computers to the DLink router.

It's maybe a bit silly to change things that works, but I want to understand the advantages of the various options, as I need to configure this more with opening ports etc for some software I'm writing.  And currently both routers have disabled firewall, so should I use the firewall in the first or 2nd router?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use both devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you are trying to use the D-Link device as a switch, not a router. You simply are using it to create more LAN ports in a different room so you only have to string a single wire from the SpeedTouch (which hosts the Internet connection) to the D-Link (where the computers are).

Based on this, you will want to connect the devices together via their LAN ports. However, you will need to shut off the DHCP server on the D-Link. When you plug the LAN ports together, the two devices become part of the same LAN; having both routers trying to give out IP addresses via DHCP will be pointless at best and cause bizarre connectivity problems at worst.

Once you've shut off the D-Link's DHCP and connected its LAN to the SpeedTouch's LAN, then the D-Link router will no longer be functioning as a router. All port-forwarding will happen through the SpeedTouch only, since it can see the computers directly.

Comment: Well, the SpeedTouch has connected 2 TV "boxes" (using 2 lan ports), and my computers are in a different room, so I run a single network cable to this room from a 3rd LAN port. In the pc-room I have the DLink.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you correctly, I should change to LAN-to-LAN, and disable DHCP in the 2nd router? Do I then still need to configure ports on both routers?

Comment: Answer updated with this new information.

Comment: Good, now I understand a bit more. And it works too! :)  Thanks!